# Usando o Identity com Entity Framework para fazer relacionameto one-to-many com outras tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

No meu cenário um usuário tem várias embarcação e uma embarcação tem vários apontamentos. Então eu preciso relacionar o usuário com a embarcação para que esse usuário possa ver esses apontamentos.

Estou o usando o template default do identity do projeto MVC 5.

Portanto, preciso relacionar a tabela AspNetUser com a tabela Barco.

Alguém ja precisou fazer isso para que possa me ajudar?

```
   public class Barco : Entity
   {

    public string Nome { get; private set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; private set; }

    public bool Excluido { get; private set; }

    public int SapId { get; private set; }

    public int CapacidadeAgua { get; private set; }

    public int CapacidadeOleo { get; private set; }

    public int Velocidade { get; private set; }

    public decimal AreaReal { get; private set; }

    public decimal AreaProgramada { get; private set; }

    public decimal AreaLivre { get; private set; }

    public string Email { get; private set; }

    public string Setor { get; private set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; private set; }



    public Guid? ClasseBarcoId { get; set; }


    public virtual ClasseBarco ClasseBarco { get; set; }




    public Barco(
        String nome, 
        bool ativo, 
        bool excluido, 
        int sapid, 
        int capacidadeAgua,
        int capacidadeOleo,
        int velocidade,
        string email,
        string setor,

        DateTime dataCadastro)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Ativo = ativo;
        Excluido = excluido;
        SapId = sapid;
        CapacidadeAgua = capacidadeAgua;
        CapacidadeOleo = capacidadeOleo;
        Velocidade = velocidade;
        Email = email;
        Setor = setor;
        DataCadastro = dataCadastro;

        ClasseBarco = new ClasseBarco();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Procure pelo seu IdentityModel.cs
em geral fica dentro de `Models/IdentityMode.cs`

Dentro de sua classe `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

Crie uma nova propriedade do tipo

```
public virtual Barco Barco {get; set;}
```

Agora na class Barco
crie uma propriedade ApplicationUser

```
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set}
```

Agora em seu  mapeamento do Application user

faça o seguinte

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.Barco)
    .WithRequired(ad => ad.ApplicationUser);

    //isso tem  que vir por ultimo
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Não tive como testar mas  creio  que isso deva resolver.

para mais informações consulte [configuring one to one relationship in asp.net identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016771/configuring-one-to-one-relationship-in-asp-net-identity)